# How to do touch input in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Basically, a simple app that when a user touches the screen, the counter on the screen increments. I have no experience whatsoever with touch inputs or have any knowledge of how to construct one properly. As far as what methods or objects I'm supposed to use, I know nothing. With a button, the touch is automatically registered. So, I want to do likewise with the screen on Windows Phone 8 using Visual Studio 2013. So far, this is the C# code I have so far with an image of what it looks like on mobile display:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int taps = 0; // create var to detect number of times, user touches the screen

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // method to register the touch as the finger is placed on the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
    }

    //method register the touch as the finger is lifting up from the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        taps++;
        counter.Text = taps.ToString(); //convert var from int to string
    }

    //method register the touch as the finger leaves the area of the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        MessageBox.Show("You left the screen without lifting your finger. That does not count as a tap!", "Caution!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    // method to reset the counter to zero when button is pressed and released
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        taps = 0; // reset the count
        counter.Text = taps.ToString(); // convert var from int to string
    }
```

[image: Windows Phone 8 Display]

Comment: This question is very similar to your second one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621670/how-to-make-the-canvas-detect-touch-input-properly-in-c/21624239#21624239

Answer (score 0):

All of the matter is `event`.

I recommend you to start to read this tutorial step by step.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

After then, read below document.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

the `Tap` event will be attached to almost all UI-related control such as `Canvas` or `Rectangle`. With `Tap` event, you can make those controls as a kind of `Button` you did already.

It would be all about what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

See, If you are looking to do it with a button then the button has a Tap event, just subscribe to it and increment the counter on every tap event call

Like this
(very simple incremental logic involved here)

```
 private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            taps++; // reset the count
            counter.Text = taps.ToString(); // convert var from int to string
        }
```

But if the same is to be implemented on a screen then put a transparent canvas control on the screen and subscribe to its mouse left button down event

```
void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                taps++; // reset the count
            counter.Text = taps.ToString(); // convert var from int to string
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown would also be called every time you tap the screen