# How to make the canvas detect touch input properly in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Basically, I'm trying to make the canvas listen for a touch input (tap) and will increment the number of taps on screen. It isn't working when I touch the screen on my device. I debugged my code and nothing seems out of the ordinary except that the touch is not detected. I checked ZIndex and the canvas is in front of the screen to be touchable. How do I make it work?

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Name="counter" FontSize="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="188,10,187,397"/>
        <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-18,535,-18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Canvas ZIndex="0" Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave"/>

</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
int taps = 0; // create var to detect number of times, user touches the screen

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // method to register the touch as the finger is placed on the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        counter.Text = "TOUCHED!";
    }

    //method register the touch as the finger is lifting up from the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        taps++;
        counter.Text = taps.ToString(); //convert var from int to string
    }

    //method register the touch as the finger leaves the area of the screen
    private void Canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        MessageBox.Show("You left the screen without lifting your finger. That does not count as a tap!", "Caution!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    // method to reset the counter to zero when button is pressed and released
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        taps = 0; // reset the count
        counter.Text = taps.ToString(); // convert var from int to string
    }
```

Comment: could you get the break point on the event while running? (I mean to say is the event getting fired?)

Comment: Yes, I set a breakpoint on all the methods and all of them aren't being fired, except the Button_Click which works.

Comment: okay now check with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to do it with `Canvas` - it won't work as you have nothing in this `Canvas`, so it can't register your click/tap, `Canvas` is also [hard to adjust to screen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/189a3ec2-de83-4a59-9aca-fb28acbf4884/windows-8-how-can-i-stretch-a-grid-within-a-canvas?forum=winappswithcsharp). I think it can be done simpler way if you want to do it with MouseUp/Down - subscribe directly to `Grid` containing your elements instead of filling this `Grid` with additional `Canvas`:

In XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"  Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="counter" FontSize="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Touched" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Touched" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2"/>                
</Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
private int taps = 0;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ContentPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown += ContentPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    ContentPanel.MouseLeftButtonUp += ContentPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp;
}

private void ContentPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   taps++;
   counter.Text = taps.ToString(); //convert var from int to string
   Touched.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void ContentPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Touched.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

// method to reset the counter to zero when button is pressed and released
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   taps = 0; // reset the count
   counter.Text = taps.ToString(); // convert var from int to string
}
```

As you can see I've subscribed to Grid events (which covers whole screen) - but to make it work I had to set its Background Brush to Transparent, otherwise it will work only if you touch text.

There are many other ways to make your App work, but I hope this will help.

Comment: It works, but not perfect. It's progress though. It only registers the touch when I touch within the textblock that holds the number. Secondly, the Reset Button is shaky everytime I tap the screen which is distracting. Any solution to these two problems?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight As I've writted - did you set Grid's Backgound to Transparent? What do you mean shaky?

Comment: It seems to fix the shaky reset button (moving up and down slightly) when I got rid of the Grid.RowDefinitions with height values of 7, 1, 1. About the Transparent, yes both LayoutRoot and ContentPanel are set to Transparent.

Comment: I have a question, is it the right way to make the textblock that includes the number and simply drag it to cover the whole screen as it now fills in the empty spaces that weren't touchable before.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight Can you run this http://sdrv.ms/1bwhtnd example? As I'm running it, everything works all right as I expect it.

Comment: yes, it's working! Thanks! How do I view the xaml code because when I immediately open your file it only shows the C# code, not the other designer window with xaml?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight You are welcome. If you are working with VS, then in SolutionExplorer window Open file.xaml (double click, or right click -> open) it should open designer window. If you see only design view, then at the border of the window you should find a buton 'XAML' which will switch to code. I'm glad I could help. Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you don't use the touch-events?
Instead of using MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp you should use TouchDown and TouchUp.

Only when you don't handle the touch events or the manipulation events they will be mapped to mouse events. In my experience with touch a single tap also not always gets mapped to MouseLeftButtonDown. As far as I know you could also with mouse events only recoginse one finger. When you want to count more fingers it's necessary to use the TouchDown/TouchUp events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the overlapping style of the grid

so either make grid rows or define a stackpanel inside the grid, something like this.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <stackpanel>
            <TextBlock Name="counter" FontSize="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <Canvas ZIndex="0" Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave"/>
            <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </stackpanel>
</Grid>
```

Try and check now.

Comment: still doesn't work and now the reset button is gone, which I'm presuming is behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your **Background** property. If you don't want any background set it to Transparent:

```
<Canvas ZIndex="99" Background="Transparent" Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" Tapped="Canvas_CountMyTaps"/>
```

(If you want the canvas to be on Top be sure to make it have a greater ZIndex than the other elements that it overlaps)

If not set (the default value is null) the element won't capture any taps/click etc, it will be as if they "fall through".

Also, consider using the [Tapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208985) event which is a "higher level" event that will respond to clicks, taps with the finger, stylus, etc.